# How to replace numbers in String with X

Tags: java, string

For Formatting account Number, i need to replace all numbers in  account number with 'X'. Is there any easy way to this other than iterating over String, compare each characters if it lies between 0-9 and replace.  Below is sample accountNumber.

12SRVV5E4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of regex for this, Please refer to below code. Here \d will match integers within String and replace it with X character. Hope this answers your doubt.

```
String accNumber="12SRVV5E4";
accNumber= accNumber.replaceAll("\\d", "X");
System.out.println(accNumber);
```